# mistakenly sent ETC to ETH address on Cryptopia

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, ethereum-classic

I have mistakenly sent ETC from Cryptopia To an ETH address.How can i recover my ETC back.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction was successful, then to recover your ETC I think you have only two options:

1. Ask the owner of the private key of that address to send you the funds.
2. Get the private key of that address and send yourself the funds.